# Should broth from a shrimp boil be refrigerated after canning?

Tags: food-preservation, broth

I searched for an answer but was unable to find an answer on the site or google. Recently I did a shrimp boil with corn, sausage, red potatoes, onions, shrimp, lemons and spices. After pulling the strainer from the 50 quart pot I took several 32 ounce ball mason jars and bottled the fluid. With the heat the lids appear to be sealed and do not pop. Should I just leave to room temp and not refrigerate or is there a proper storage procedure?

The left over broth will be used for jambalaya and I doubt I’ll have any of it longer than 6 months. When jarred the broth was not strained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the broth at room temperature, it needs to be [pressure canned](https://www.freshpreserving.com/pressure-canning.html), as do [all stocks and broths](https://www.theprairiehomestead.com/2012/12/how-to-can-homemade-stock-or-broth.html) with animal ingredients.  Advice on [times and pressures](https://ask.extension.org/questions/159954) varies, but assuming that you don't really care to go back and pressure can it, I'd just keep it in the fridge or freezer (if freezing, have plenty of headroom in those jars).